# API.AI system entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using API.AI system entity: @sys.given-name and it does not work on all kind of names,for example if I give some classic indian names like naresh, rahul, etc, then it goes to default fallback intent. Does anyone know how this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar experience and problem using @sys.given-name for Dutch names. The company I'm working for requested for a functionality where information about an exmployee could be displayed by asking for someones name.

The way I've solved this issue is by using the @sys.any entity. @sys.any will capture any string responses as an entity in user query. From there I parse the @sys.any:name in my webhook and compare it with a string matching algorithm to a list of names from a database.

My user utterances in that intent look something like this:

```
I'd like to know more about @sys.any:name
Who is @sys.any:name
What do you know about @sys.any:name
```

This solution has been working decently and reliably for me.

Comment: hello, thanks for responding back. At this moment, like you said comparing with a list of possible names is a good option, but I was looking for a way by which the agent can automatically understand instead of searching the DB.

Comment: @BhavyaBansal You can recommend Indian name list to Dialogflow
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#name-en

Comment: @BhavyaBansal Correct, I compare it to a list of names from a tenant from the Microsoft Graph API. It's not a list of names I build up myself but actual people working for the company. For me, this was the easiest and most reliable solution without modifying entities or anything else when new people are hired to the company.